# Sending login requests to ASP.NET Web Site with Python requests lib

Tags: python, http-post

I'm trying to make a login request to an ASP.NET site.

I tried manually with postman, it's ok. But while trying to with python requests lib, I'm getting a HTTP 500 error. Actualy I tried many libs/urllibs and beautiful soap. But I couldn't succeed.

Here are my codes:

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
headers = {
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Host':'www.host.com',
}
payload = {'user':'******',
           'password':'******',
           'rememberMe':'false',
           '__RequestVerificationToken':'<my-verification-token>'
           }
link    = 'https://www.host.com/login'
resp=requests.post(link,data=payload,headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
```

There is a CAPTCHA control on the website's login, can CAPTCHA be causing this error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What were your input values when you were sending a request within POSTMAN? How did you get over CAPTCHA?

Comment: @Seckin ,it can login without enter captcha values with in postman

Comment: `__RequestVerificatinToken` can be different at every request and server checks it. you have to GET page, find this token in HTML and use it in POST. And use `requests.Session()` to use in POST all cookies which server sends to you in GET.

Comment: save resp.text in file and see inweb browser. maybe there is useful message.

Comment: @furas,i did it  Also in for  previous comment  I asked .net developers ,They say ,you can login with  same RequestVerificatinToken  for a short time.But then you must change and make it dynamic.So Im changing token but it doesnt work.

Comment: script has to behave like browser - ie. use cookies, send hidden or empty fields, send the same headers. Server may check it too.